# cpanel auto generate bandwidth and RAM report

Tags: cpanel, ram, bandwidth, whm

I've server hosting with another company.
Usually i monitor my server bandwidth by accessing Cpanel>log> Bandwidth.
Also access to WHM to check server RAM Usage.
But is it possible to create a cron job for daily auto generate bandwidth report and RAM usage to my Email?

I'm new to server hosting, is there any dummy way to create auto generate?
Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor and analyze server resource  with the Munin, If you have root access, you can install Munin Server Monitor plugin on your server through WHM >> cPanel >> Manage Plugins >> munin

Comment: Hi 24x7,
is that possible for using munin to create cronjob for compile bandwidth and send email by everyday?